# How to Create Customer Group and Product Attribute with Script / Programmatic of type drop down and having values as customer name?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, setup-script, programmatically

I want to create attribute through script of drop down type. in Drop down i want to display Customer Name of particular group.
and also want to create customer group with script how its possible?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Is only one customer per group? Approach: Add attribute with source model, source model get all customer groups and customers and returns them.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt no i wanted to create one customer group.
and in product one attribute which is drop-down type which is display Customer Name of above created group type.
i got solution as below.
By The Way Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here First I post How to Create Customer group througt setup-script or programmatically?

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$customer_group=Mage::getModel('customer/group');
$customer_group->setCode("Label Of customer Group");
$customer_group->setTaxClassId(3);
$customer_group->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now, we will see how to create product attribute through setup-script / programmatically?

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                       

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code', array(
             'group'             => 'ATTIBUTE GROUP NAME', // it will create new tab if you want to create new tab like general,inventory etc... etc...
             'label'             => 'ATTIBUTE LABEL NAME',
             'type'              => 'varchar',
             'input'             => 'select',
             'backend'           => '',
             'frontend'          => '', 
             'source'            => 'MODULENAME/source_option', //Path of Model file Where you will create option
             'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'           => true,
             'required'          => true,
             'user_defined'      => true,
             'searchable'        => false,
             'filterable'        => false,
             'comparable'        => false,
             'visible_on_front'  => false,
             'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
             'unique'            => false,
             'apply_to'          => 'simple,grouped,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now Model File which returns option value for drop-down.

```
class Name_Modulename_Model_Source_Option extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract{

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', 5);
        // Group_id 5 is cretaed new group for custoerm
        $options = array();
        foreach ($customerCollection as $customer){
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());

            $options[] = $customer->getName();
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

If you want to create Static(Fixed option value) for drop-down type product attribute.

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                       

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code', array(
             'group'             => ''ATTIBUTE GROUP NAME', // it will create new tab if you want to create new tab like general,inventory etc... etc...
             'label'             => 'ATTIBUTE LABEL NAME',
             'type'              => 'varchar',
             'input'             => 'select',
             'backend'           => '',
             'frontend'          => '', 
             'source'            => '',
             'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'           => true,
             'required'          => true,
             'user_defined'      => true,
             'searchable'        => false,
             'filterable'        => false,
             'comparable'        => false,
             'option'            => array (
                                            'value' => array('value1' => array('Label1'),
                                                             'value2' => array('Lbel2'),
                                                            )
                                          ),
             'visible_on_front'  => false,
             'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
             'unique'            => false,
             'apply_to'          => 'simple,grouped,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'

));
```

Comment: I have created a module to create customercustomer in manufacturer customer group now I want to add this manufacturer customer group as a product attribute to product so that when I create a product from admin there should be an dropdown list from the manufacturer customer group to add the manufacturer of the product.